# How would I go about resizing this hash table?

Tags: java, hashtable

Here is how the class is implemented and then I have the resize function where I created a new array but I'm not sure where to go from there.

```
private int N;                                // number of strings
private int M;                                // hash table size
private Node[] st;                            // array of linked-lists

private class Node {
    String key;
    Node next;

    public Node(String s) {
        key = s;
    }

    public Node(String s, Node n) {
        this(s);
        next = n;
    }
}

// resize the hash table to have the given number of chains b rehashing all of the keys
private void resize(int newM) {
    // TODO
    Node[] temp = (Node[]) new Node[newM];



}
```

Comment: This looks to a certain degree like you are supposed to enhance existing code as part of homework; and you try to dump the actual work ... on other people.

Comment: I just need a little help on where to go from here..

Comment: You're going to need to go through the old array, find all the entries from that array, and copy them over to new hash entries in the new array.

Comment: Then you have to spent some more energy; as of now it is not clear where exactly you are stuck. Your current code doesn't contain **anything** substantial at all.